# REGEXEXTRACT function exact match

Tags: google-sheets

I applied this function on D2, and it works but matching should be case sensitive. At this moment, it  match anyting similar. Example, It repeats Intern for International or Internal. But it should not do this way. If Intern not found on Title (C), then should show nothing. Pls help.
`INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)))`

Here  is image link: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1gkQ1eOfupBeAnkHjQC97ALNKvHSS5l3v6BkqMUSrMX4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a try with this:

`=BYROW(C2:C,LAMBDA(cx,if(cx="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(cx,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(E2:E,"(.+)","\\b$1\\b"))))))))`

-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(C2:C, 1, 0))))
```